# Need to declare time and want the getdate() to return only date and join both the results

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a column as time something like this

```
time        
2016-04-05 23:41:00
```

I want to make a job where it will insert the time automatically. but the problem I am facing is from `getdate()` I am getting today current date and time.

Can we declare time and only get the date from `getdate()` function?

Something like:

```
declare @time = '07:00:00'+convert(varchar(10),getdate()-1,120)
```

I want in the **output** as `2016-04-05 07:00:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to cast the value you get back from `GetDate()` to `Date` data type and back to `DateTime`, and add the value of Time to it (cast it from `Time` datatype to `DateTime`), like this:

```
DECLARE @Time time = '07:00:00'

SELECT  GETDATE() As CurrentTime, 
        CAST(CAST(GETDATE() As Date) As Datetime) + CAST(@Time as datetime) As TimeToday
```

Results

```
CurrentTime                 TimeToday
-----------------------     -----------------------
2016-07-06 04:13:11.090     2016-07-06 07:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
declare @time varchar(20) = convert(varchar(20),getdate(),120)
```